# Spring boot application not rendering index.jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

After searching out all the possible solutions I'm posting this out.

My spring boot application was running fine few days ago. I was able to deploy it on tomcat and also export the war and deploy it on my application server. But suddenly it is showing blank page on deployment. What could be the possible reasons?

In pom.xml I've all the dependencies:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sdigital</groupId>
    <artifactId>cheapTravelTicket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name></name>
    <description>cheap Travel Ticket</description>
  <!--  Default from spring boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
         <!--  Web Application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring  data jpa -->

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Spring  Webservices -->

        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.w3c/dom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.w3c</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/sax/sax -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sax</groupId>
            <artifactId>sax</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

         <!--  Embedded Tomcat -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <!-- Slug generator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.slugify</groupId>
            <artifactId>slugify</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

       <!-- Common String -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons IO --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP,
            tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, no idea why -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>     
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>       
          </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcabi/jcabi-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-xml</artifactId>
            <version>0.18.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
         <!--  Spring boot maven support -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Application class is as follows:

```
package com.sdigital;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.sdigital.cache.ExpiringMap;




/**
 * The Class CTTApplication.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class CTTApplication {

    /**
     * The main method.
     *boots the application
     * 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(CTTApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> getCache(){
    Map<String, Object> map = ExpiringMap.builder()
       .maxSize(200)
       .expiration(12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
       .build();    
     return map;
    }

}
```

ServletInitializer

```
package com.sdigital;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;


// TODO: Auto-generated Javadoc
/**
 * The Class ServletInitializer.
 */
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * SpringApplication Builder
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {        

        return application.sources(CTTApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
package com.sdigital.controller;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.sdigital.bus.distribution.domain.ConnectionRequest;
import com.sdigital.cache.SearchCache;
import com.sdigital.domain.JourneyRequest;
import com.sdigital.domain.TimeTableRequest;
import com.sdigital.domain.XmlUrl;
import com.sdigital.domain.XmlUrlSet;
import com.sdigital.model.BusProvider;
import com.sdigital.model.City;
import com.sdigital.model.CustomForm;
import com.sdigital.model.Route;
import com.sdigital.model.SeoConfig;
import com.sdigital.model.SiteMap;
import com.sdigital.repositories.BusProviderRepository;
import com.sdigital.repositories.CityRepository;
import com.sdigital.repositories.RouteRepository;
import com.sdigital.repositories.SeoConfigRepository;
import com.sdigital.repositories.SiteMapRepository;
import com.sdigital.repositories.StationConfigRepository;
import com.sdigital.service.AppService;
import com.sdigital.utils.CTTConstant;
import com.sdigital.utils.CommonUtils;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"searchRequest", "searchBusRequest"})
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private AppService appServc;

    @Autowired
    private StationConfigRepository strepo;

    @Autowired
    private RouteRepository rtrepo;

    @Autowired
    private CityRepository ctrepo;

    @Autowired
    private BusProviderRepository busrepo;

    @Autowired
    private SeoConfigRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    private SearchCache searchCache;

    @Autowired
    private SiteMapRepository siteMap;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home(){
        //List<Route> cttPopular = rtrepo.findOneByPopularType(CTTConstant.CTT_POPULAR_TYPE);
        List<City> cttPopular = ctrepo.findAllByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        List<Route> popular = rtrepo.findByPopularType(CTTConstant.POPULAR_TYPE);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("cttPopular", cttPopular);
        model.addObject("popular", popular);
        SeoConfig seoCon = repo.findByPageType(3);
        model.addObject("title", seoCon.getPageTitle());
        model.addObject("meta_title", seoCon.getMetaTitle());
        model.addObject("meta_description", seoCon.getMetaDescription());
        model.addObject("meta_keywords", seoCon.getMetaKeywords());
        model.addObject("seo_url", seoCon.getSeoUrl());
        model.addObject("description", seoCon.getDescription());
        model.addObject("desc1", seoCon.getDesc1());
        model.addObject("desc2", seoCon.getDesc2());
        model.addObject("desc3", seoCon.getDesc3());
        List<City> topCities = ctrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        List<Route> topRoutes = rtrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        model.addObject("topCities", topCities);
        model.addObject("topRoutes", topRoutes);
        List<BusProvider> topBusProviders = busrepo.findTop10ByPublishOrderByPriorityAsc(true);
        model.addObject("topBusProviders", topBusProviders);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/book")
    public ModelAndView portalBook(@ModelAttribute("journeyRequest") JourneyRequest  journeyRequest) throws URISyntaxException {
        ModelAndView m = null;
        m = appServc.getView(journeyRequest);
        return m;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/search")
    public ModelAndView portalSearch(@ModelAttribute("searchRequest") TimeTableRequest  searchRequest, 
            @RequestParam(name="sort_by", required = false) String sortBy,
            @RequestParam(name="s", required = false) String start,
            @RequestParam(name="orig", required = false) String originuic,
            @RequestParam(name="dest", required = false) String destinationuic, HttpSession session){

        /*System.out.println("*** Session data ***");
          Enumeration<String> e = session.getAttributeNames();
          while (e.hasMoreElements()){
            String s = e.nextElement();
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println("**" + session.getAttribute(s));
          }*/

        if(originuic!=null && destinationuic!=null){
            searchRequest.setChildren(0);
            searchRequest.setRailcards(null);
            searchRequest.setTravelclass("standard");
            searchRequest.setRetdatetime(null);
            searchRequest.setAdults(1);
            searchRequest.setDestinationuic(destinationuic);
            searchRequest.setOriginuic(originuic);  
            searchRequest.setReturnjry(false);
            searchRequest.setOutdatetime(CommonUtils.getFormatedDate(CTTConstant.DEFAULT_SEARCH_FORMAT, new Date()));
            searchRequest.setOutsearchTime(CommonUtils.getCurrentUTCTimeSearchable(false));
        }

        ModelAndView m = appServc.getView(searchRequest, sortBy, start);
        List<City> topCities = ctrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        List<Route> topRoutes = rtrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        m.addObject("topCities", topCities);
        m.addObject("topRoutes", topRoutes);
        List<BusProvider> topBusProviders = busrepo.findTop10ByPublishOrderByPriorityAsc(true);
        m.addObject("topBusProviders", topBusProviders);
        m.addObject("currentDate", CommonUtils.getFormatedDate(CTTConstant.DEFAULT_SEARCH_FORMAT, new Date()));
        return m;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("searchRequest")
    public TimeTableRequest createFormModelAttribute(HttpSession session) {
        TimeTableRequest req = (TimeTableRequest)session.getAttribute("searchRequest"); 
        if(req!=null)
            return req;
        TimeTableRequest req1 = new TimeTableRequest();
        req1.setAdults(1);
        req1.setOutdatetime(CommonUtils.getFormatedDate(CTTConstant.DEFAULT_SEARCH_FORMAT, new Date()));
        req1.setOutsearchTime(CommonUtils.getCurrentUTCTimeSearchable(false));
        req1.setRetsearchTime(CommonUtils.getCurrentUTCTimeSearchable(true));
        return req1;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/bus-search")
    public ModelAndView portalSearch(@ModelAttribute("searchBusRequest") ConnectionRequest  searchRequest, 
            @RequestParam(name="sort_by", required = false) String sortBy,
            @RequestParam(name="s", required = false) String start,
            @RequestParam(name="orig", required = false) String originuic,
            @RequestParam(name="dest", required = false) String destinationuic, HttpSession session){

        if(originuic!=null && destinationuic!=null){
            searchRequest.setChildren1(0);
            searchRequest.setRetdatetime(null);
            searchRequest.setAdults1(1);
            searchRequest.setDestinationuic1(destinationuic);
            searchRequest.setOriginuic1(originuic); 
            searchRequest.setReturnjry(false);
            searchRequest.setCurrency("EUR");
            searchRequest.setDatetime(CommonUtils.getFormatedDate(CTTConstant.DEFAULT_SEARCH_FORMAT, new Date()));
        }

        ModelAndView m = appServc.getView(searchRequest, sortBy, start);
        List<City> topCities = ctrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        List<Route> topRoutes = rtrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        m.addObject("topCities", topCities);
        m.addObject("topRoutes", topRoutes);
        List<BusProvider> topBusProviders = busrepo.findTop10ByPublishOrderByPriorityAsc(true);
        m.addObject("topBusProviders", topBusProviders);
        m.addObject("currentDate", CommonUtils.getFormatedDate(CTTConstant.DEFAULT_SEARCH_FORMAT, new Date()));
        return m;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("searchBusRequest")
    public ConnectionRequest createFormModelAttribute() {
        return new ConnectionRequest();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("journeyRequest")
    public JourneyRequest createFormModelAttribute1() {
        return new JourneyRequest();
    }    

    @RequestMapping(value="/{seo:.+}")
    public ModelAndView portalLocation(@PathVariable("seo") String seo, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(name="status", required = false) String status){
        ModelAndView m = appServc.getView(seo, response, status);
        List<City> topCities = ctrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        List<Route> topRoutes = rtrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        m.addObject("topCities", topCities);
        m.addObject("topRoutes", topRoutes);
        List<BusProvider> topBusProviders = busrepo.findTop10ByPublishOrderByPriorityAsc(true);
        m.addObject("topBusProviders", topBusProviders);
        return m;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{seo1}/{seo2:.+}")
    public ModelAndView portalChildLocation(@PathVariable("seo1") String seo1, @PathVariable("seo2") String seo2, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(name="status", required = false) String status){
        ModelAndView m = appServc.getView(seo1+"/"+seo2, response, status);
        List<City> topCities = ctrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        List<Route> topRoutes = rtrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        m.addObject("topCities", topCities);
        m.addObject("topRoutes", topRoutes);
        List<BusProvider> topBusProviders = busrepo.findTop10ByPublishOrderByPriorityAsc(true);
        m.addObject("topBusProviders", topBusProviders);
        return m;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/schedular/trains")
    public boolean portalSchedularToUpdateTrains(){
        appServc.updateTrainsForCityToCity();
        return true;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/robots.txt")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getRobots(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "User-agent: * \n Disallow: /";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sitemap.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public XmlUrlSet getSiteMap(HttpServletRequest request) {
        XmlUrlSet xmlUrlSet = new XmlUrlSet();
        create(xmlUrlSet, "", "1.0", request);          
        List<SiteMap> seoUrls = siteMap.findByPublish(1);
        for(SiteMap sUrl : seoUrls){
            create(xmlUrlSet, "/"+sUrl.getSeoUrl(), null, request);
        }
        return xmlUrlSet;
    }

    private void create(XmlUrlSet xmlUrlSet, String link, String priority, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String rootUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + request.getContextPath();
        xmlUrlSet.addUrl(new XmlUrl(rootUrl + link, priority));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/information/rail-cards")
    public ModelAndView railCardInfo(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("railinfo");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/form/post")
    public String formPost(@ModelAttribute("addRequest") CustomForm  addRequest){
        String r = appServc.addData(addRequest);
        return r;
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView("exception");
        List<City> topCities = ctrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        List<Route> topRoutes = rtrepo.findTop10ByOrderByPriorityAsc();
        m.addObject("topCities", topCities);
        m.addObject("topRoutes", topRoutes);
        List<BusProvider> topBusProviders = busrepo.findTop10ByPublishOrderByPriorityAsc(true);
        m.addObject("topBusProviders", topBusProviders);
        m.addObject("searchRequest", new TimeTableRequest());
        return m;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more with the controller details

Comment: Can you check the browser and application console and tell if anything there?

Comment: No logs on browser console. It shows 200. Also there are no errors on application console.

Comment: Where is your SpringBootServletInitializer  and the path for that and where is your default controller.

Comment: @mallikarjun I added the servletinitializer and controller details above

Comment: everything looks good have you tried with maven boot:run?

Comment: Try doing clean package and also do a force maven update then check

Comment: I tried maven clean / maven update / mvn eclipse:eclipse but nothing is working out

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer in case anyone else faces same issue.
Problem was with the context path. Updated the context path in project properties in eclipse. then ran clean and build. Most important part was to remove the server configuration and again ran it on tomcat, it worked.

Since I was not clearing the server configurations from eclipse updated context path was not picking up.